# Whether however or though

Tags: adverbs

Wild monkeys are a problem for many areas in Japan. Every year they cause heavy damage to crops._______ the farmers are fighting back.

In the above blank whether **though or however** should be used.
I am confused. I searched for the difference between though and however but did not find anything satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

> Wild monkeys are a problem for many areas in Japan. Every year they
> cause heavy damage to crops. **However**, the farmers are fighting
> back.

That should be the correct answer since the word is used to **introduce** a remark that contrasts with or appears to contradict **anything previously said**.

You can use though since it's synonymous with however, but **'however'** is a much better word to use. Unless you change though with *although*, only then.

- Whether isn't really a choice since it's used where you demonstrate that two things can happen. Or rather stating that a remark applies to whatever possibilities are in a situation.

Comment: If you can't add commas, then **though** is the answer. Also, I'm confused are you indicating that only whether, however or though should be used, or whether however or though should be used?